# How to avoid losing logs with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have this scenario.

We have a log archiving script which archives logs that are older than 8 days. We want to make sure that we don't lose any logs until we've archived them.

I have set `maxBackupIndex` to 10 and `maxFileSize` to 10MB. If I get more transactions within 8 days, which take more than 100MB of logs, then there is a possibility that I might lose some logs.

How can I avoid this situation? Can I set `maxBackupIndex` to infinity?

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but this a a particular sore point with me. The word is "losing", not "loosing". I'll fix that and also the infuriating habit people have of not capitalising the personal pronoun (it's "I", not "i"). Please take better care in future :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Good point, the losing/loosing mistake is something that i also find annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a script to compress files older than a day if you have trouble retaining the logs.

`maxFileSize` is an `int`. You can set it to 1000000000 or whatever would use too much disk space.  Youc an also increase the `maxFileSize` to 100MB or 1GB.

Comment: but when file size become large , it can not be opened in any editor right. so there is no point in making large files.

Comment: I use `less` and `vi` and it can cope with 1-3 GB text files. I would see if you editor can handle files larger than 10 MB which is that big these days.

Comment: I opened a 100 MB text file with notepad++ in 2 seconds, and a 200 MB text file took 12 seconds.

Comment: don't log4.j has a solution like this. it rotates logs daily. say max file size is 100MB. let's say there is day where 150MB size logs are generated. in that case, it will create 2 log files as logfilename.today.checksum logfilename.today.checsum. based on checsum it can create many files per day. but if it get 90MB logs per day then it only have to create logfilename.today file.

Comment: That sounds more manageable. Less logs files are usually easier to work with IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Set maxBackupIndex and maxFileSize to numbers high enough to allow retention of a reasonable workload, but not so high as to cause disk space to be exceeded.

Then create an external task (cron or windows scheduled task) to remove/archive logs older than 8 days.